# Xamarin Mobile Device to SQLite stored on AWS Ec2

Tags: rest, sqlite, tomcat, xamarin, amazon-ec2

As the title goes, I need to connect a Xamarin built application to a SQLITE database stored inside a Amazon EC2 that is hosting a web app.

Now I agree not the most robust of set ups but i'm aware it can be done using **RESTful API**  to build a web service and ideally host on Tomcat. But i can't find out how. Totally new to APIs.

That's all I need really. I've been down most avenues of Google and Xamarin support docs. But I really need someone to point me in the right direction as im seeing alot of broken links for Xamarin docs that revert me to Microsofts site. Or help find an example, anything would be heavily appreciated. I can only offer that if you answer my question you will make someones day and I will post a cute picture of a hamster.

Thanks!

Comment: Googling "build a rest api" returns dozens of examples.

Comment: Really @Jason, thats what you bringing to the table? Google it? trust me my friend, I have tried. I am sorry something in your journey into stackoverflow to help has made you bitter enough for that reply.

Comment: Bing'ing "build a rest api" returns dozens of examples and several Github projects, such as: https://github.com/assafmo/SQLiteProxy And only my coffee is bitter.

Comment: I could spend an hour writing up a 10 page tutorial on creating a REST API.  Or I could suggest that you read one of the dozens of existing tutorials that already exist.  That seems perfectly reasonable - and not at all bitter - to me.

Comment: Not asking for that, just a point in the right direction for my set up above because there are so many different ways of building an API, I cannot find one that relates. I appreciate your motive to help and thanks to @SushiHangover for the github recommendation, constructive.